# Replacing input type=date as Javascript code. Calendar/Time not showing

Tags: javascript, php, datetimepicker

Good day

I first used to use input type="date" but then saw that it's not supported in firefox.

So, now I am using below code but still calendar not showing up

Help

Thanks

**HTML:**

```
<input class="input" name="dateNew" id="datetimepicker" type="text"/>
```

**Jquery:**

```
<body>

<script>
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
</script>
</body>
```

**After < / body>**

```
<!-- this should go after your </body> -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `datetimepicker();` after you've included it's JS files, so it should be after the following line.

```
<script src="/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>
```

HTML will look something like this,

```
<body>
    <!-- this should go after your </body> -->
</body>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
</script>
```

Comment: I used this now as per you said.. after </body> tag

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >
<script src="/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
</script>

but still not worked

Comment: Yes!
1- Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

2- http://localhost:8080/jquery.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

3- http://localhost:8080/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

4- http://localhost:8080/jquery.datetimepicker.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: 5- http://localhost:8080/jquery.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
6- http://localhost:8080/build/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
equipments.php:568 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).datetimepicker is not a function

7- http://localhost:8080/jquery.datetimepicker.css Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: http://localhost:8080/jquery.datetimepicker.css Failed to load resource:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).datetimepicker is not a function

Comment: Above errors shows that it's not able to locate the JS files, make sure they're on the right URL path you're referencing from.

Answer (score 0):

Please change:

```
jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
```

to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     jQuery('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker();
})
```

Comment: Is that a file named "jquery.js" in your project? I think you didn't load file in the right way

Comment: @Chiff Zhu No, I am writing script in the same php file under script. I think heres a mistake. Should remove this reference?

Comment: No, I am writing script in the same php file under script. I think heres a mistake. Should remove this reference?

Comment: "/jquery.js" and "/jquery.datetimepicker.css" are files path, you need got these files first. look at this page: [link](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp) there are some basic knowledge

Comment: I know actually but i exactly followed this link:

http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/

I dont know where he gave these field

Comment: Download the "Download.zip" from this link: [xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/archive/master.zip), extract and copy the files you need to your project

Answer (score 0):

So I am answering my own question now :)

I have solved using date picker instead of date time picker. I only need date now not time, so I did :

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(function(){
    var pickerOpts = {
        dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
    };  
    $("#datepicker").datepicker(pickerOpts);
});

  </script>
<head>
<body>
<input class="input" name="dateNew" id="datepicker" type="text"/>

</body>
</html>
```